# cannot design a three-dimensional array in odoo

Tags: arrays, odoo

I have 2 models, site model and legal_text model, when I enter to the site view, odoo shows me the list of texts (in a notebook page) and I can decide if a legal text is applicable in this site or not. Here's my code:

```
class site(models.Model):
    _name ='ab.site'
    name = fields.Char('Name')
    tel = fields.Integer('Phone')
    fax = fields.Integer('Fax')  
    street=fields.Char(string="street")
    street2= fields.Char(string="street2")
    zip= fields.Char(string="zip")
    city=fields.Char(string="city")
    site_responsible= fields.Many2one('res.users', 'Site Responsible')
    text_ids = fields.Many2many('ab.text',
                            'ab_site_text_rel',
                            'text_id',
                            'site_id',
                            'Texts')
    applicability_id = fields.Many2one('ab.applicability', 'Applicability')

class text(models.Model):
    _name = 'ab.text' 
    name = fields.Char('Title', required=True)
    type = fields.Selection(
    [
        ('European_directive', 'European directive'),
        ('European_Regulation', 'European Regulation'),
        ('Law', 'Law'),
        ('Decree', 'Decree'),
        ('order', 'Order'),
        ('Circular', 'Circular'),
        ('Notice', 'Notice'),
        ('Decision', 'Decision'),
        ('Prescription', 'Prescription'),
    ],
    'Type')
    applicability_id = fields.Many2one('ab.applicability', 'Applicability')
    signedDate = fields.Date('SignedDate') 
    startingDate = fields.Date('StartingDate')
    content = fields.Text('Content')


class applicability(models.Model):       
    _name = 'ab.applicability'
    name = fields.Boolean("Applicable?")
    site_ids = fields.One2many('ab.site',
                           'applicability_id',
                           'Sites')
    text_ids = fields.One2many('ab.text',
                           'applicability_id',
                           'Texts')


<record id="ab_text_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">ab.text.tree</field>
    <field name="model">ab.text</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Texts" editable="top">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="applicability_id"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>


<record model="ir.ui.view" id="site_form_view">
        <field name="name">site.form</field>
        <field name="model">ab.site</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Site">
            <sheet>
                <notebook string="General Information">                
                        <page string="Texts">
                            <field name="text_ids"/>
                        </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

The problem is that a text can be applicable in site and not in another. So the applicability is related not to the site only or the text only but to both at the same time. It's like I'm having a three-dimensional array:

```
 site * text * applicability
```

I can't find a solution to this!

Answer (score 0):

Tessnim ..., I propose to create juste one model (site), with its fields and two other fields ( selections field and boolean field ), do you understand?

Comment: this will work if I had a small list of texts, but I have a table containing thousands of legal texts, so I can't create only a selection field. Now for the boolean field, I can't add it to the site because it's related to the text also (the applicability of a text on a site) and if I add it to the text table, this won't work too cause a text can be applicable on a site and not on another

Comment: So, with same idea but replace selection filed  by many2one with legal texte model. In this case you can create  for example site01 with legal-text01 not applicable ,you can also  create other site with same  legal texte but with different  boolean value ( applicable)

Comment: But I have many texts applicable on the same site, so I need a many2many relation here. So I don't have one boolean value, for one site I have many texts and each text with its applicability value.

Comment: yes I do, Tessnim, List to me, in applicability class make just two fileds value applicable (boolean) and text_ids but many2one (ab.text), now go to site class delete text_ids field. now should be work like you want. in this case you will have many of legal text with its value applicable for one site